# Stored Procedure errors out only when calling from a trigger

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers

I am using SQL Server to programming something that's triggered by a UPDATE even in a table.

So the structure is like: in the trigger, I have:

```
EXEC StoredProcedure1
```

And in `StoredProcedure1` I have:

```
INSERT dbo.UnbalancedFreqStops
    SELECT APremise AS PremiseID
        ,geography::ConvexHullAggregate(Location) AS Shape
    FROM 
        (SELECT 
             A.[Premise ID] AS APremise, B.[Premise ID] AS BPremise,
             B.LatLon AS Location, B.[Service Frequency] AS FreqT, B.Mon_Routed AS MonT,
             B.Tue_Routed AS TueT, B.Wed_Routed AS WedT, B.Thu_Routed AS ThuT, 
             B.Fri_Routed AS FriT, B.Sat_Routed AS SatT, B.Sun_Routed AS SunT  
         FROM 
             dbo.Weekly AS A 
        INNER JOIN 
             dbo.Weekly AS B ON A.LatLon.STDistance(B.LatLon) <= (80 * 2) 
        ) AS Clusters 
   GROUP BY 
       APremise    
   HAVING 
       MAX(FreqT) <> (MAX(MonT) + MAX(TueT) + MAX(WedT) + MAX(ThuT) + MAX(FriT) + MAX(SatT) + MAX(SunT));
```

It's interesting that it errors out with violation of primary key error (`PremiseId` being unique PK) ONLY WHEN I am calling the stored procedure from the trigger. And the stored procedure runs fine if I (1) run it alone, or (2) call it from another stored procedure.

Moreover, I ran the query alone, and found there is NO duplicate key AT ALL.

Can somebody enlighten me?

Thanks!

Comment: In the trigger, you just execute the stored procedure, without any context whatsoever from what rows were affected by the trigger? That seems rather odd to me...

Comment: Are you sure your trigger is only called once and only execute the same code one time and not try to insert 2 lines identic? Try to debug or make a trace inserting a count or something with key.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't make up this error message for fun, so while you say `there is NO duplicate key AT ALL`, you're wrong.